# В чем разница вызова функций?

Tags: golang

Пытаюсь осмыслить подход вызова функций с помощью анонимных функций. И не понимаю зачем нужны анонимные функции в golang. Вот например в чем отличие подхода

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var i, j int
    fmt.Scan(&i, &j)
    fmt.Println(sum(i, j))
}

func sum(i, j int) int {
    return i + j
}
```

От подхода

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var i, j int
    fmt.Scan(&i, &j)
    fmt.Println(do(i, j, sum))
}

func sum(i, j int) int {
    return i + j
}

func do(i, j int, f func(int, int) int) int {
    return f(i, j)
}
```

Во втором варианте, помимо очевидного усложнения вызова функции sum() и помимо абстрагирования от нее же, я, пока что, смысла не вижу. Что можно сделать вторым способом такого, чего нельзя первым? Мне, конечно, радостно, что я +- могу реализовать оба подхода, но зачем мне второй, если он сложнее?

Comment: Например: функция сортировки должна как-то принимать массив и критерий сортировки (оператор сравнения элементов).

Comment: Анонимная функция, в действительности, более сложный объект, чем просто функция. Это functional closure - функция, которая может обращаться не только к своим параметрам и глобальным переменным, но так же к локальным переменным, которые были видимы в точке определения функции. Пример https://go.dev/tour/moretypes/25

Comment: @PakUula  как работает функция я понял но не понял один момет в ее выполнении. Почему `pos(i)` делает `res+i`, а `neg(-2*i)` не делает, хоть  и оба случая делают adder...

Comment: Вообще говоря, я сам недолюбливаю анонимные функции. Однажды я получил незабываемый опыт, отлаживая лямбду внутри лямбды внутри лямбды, и все функции были здоровенные, по два-три экрана. Вот с тех пор и предпочитаю только именованные функции. Тем более в Го, где есть такие замечательные вещи, как интерфейсы и методы. Вместо closures я предпочитаю поля структуры, а вместо функциональных параметров - параметрый интерфейсных типов. Да, нужно писать больше кода, но зато всё явно и наглядно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот простой пример. Функция filter применяет другую функцию, чтобы отфильтровать значения в списке.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func filter[T comparable](data []T, f func(T) bool) []T {
    flt := make([]T, 0, len(data))
    
    for _, v := range data {
        if f(v) {
            flt = append(flt, v)
        }
    }
    return flt
}

func main() {
    a1 := filter(
        []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6},
        func(i int) bool {
            return i%2 == 0
        },
    )

    a2 := filter(
        []string{"Alice", "Dwane", "Ammy", "William", "Andrew"},
        func(i string) bool {
            return !strings.HasPrefix(i, "A")
        },
    )
    fmt.Println(a1)
    fmt.Println(a2)
}
```

Comment: честно говоря, разобравшись в примере, прихожу к выводу, что он демонстрирует, как раз, излишнее усложение простой операции..

Comment: @Quester Да, это на первый взгляд усложнение, но это и гибкость. Когда вы можете один и тот же код потом использовать с разными функциями в качестве параметра. Такое тоже бывает нужно.

Comment: @Quester вы же понимает, что функция может быть гораздо тяжелее чем этот простой пример. А так это работает +/- во всех языках, в том же Python тоже есть функции filter, map, any, reduce из коробки и люди ими пользуются.

Comment: @NormanBytes так я же и не спору что рботает...Вопрос то в том, почему нельзя это сделать простым способом. Мне бы пример что делается ТОЛЬКО анонимной функцией и никак по-другому..Пока что примеры сводятся к тому что простая операция усложнилась и код стал менее наглядным и требуется больше времени, чтобы разобраться что тон делает

Comment: Все я понял для чего это)))